# How to make a structure or hierarchy with tuples as derivatives?

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures, hierarchy

I want to make a structure or a related hierarchy in Python where, for ex: A name `xxxx` is appended to a list, and under `xxxx` multiple "ID's" are stored? and upon searching an ID it would return under which `xxxx` it has been stored.

To make this more clear, for `xxxx` and `yyyy`:

```
xxxx -  |- 112       yyyy - |- 123
        |- 113              |- 124
        |- 114              |- 125
```

and upon searching for any of these ID's it would return the group to which it belongs to, i.e if I search for `114`, it would return that it belongs to `yyyy`.

```
class Post:
    ID            =  []
    incoming_data =  ''
    Buff          =  0
    IP            =  []
    contact_info  =  ''

    def Map(self, object):
       object.contact_info = object.IP + object.ID
       print object.contact_info

obj1 = Post()
obj1.incoming = '112113114115116'
obj1.IP.append('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')

for x in range(1,6): #seperates it into sets of 3 digit numbers.
    obj1.ID.append(obj1.incoming_data[(3 * x) - 3: 3 * x])

obj1.Map(obj1)       #Prints the concatenated value of the both the strings.
```

I've come to this point where it puts it as a string but I should I be using tuples for this? I'm kind of new, and I've stared only a few hours back, any help is appreciated. I'd like to know possible methods.

Present output:

```
['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116']
```

Comment: You mean tuples. Also, I think you're looking for dictionaries.

Comment: @COLDSPEED any elaboration on how I could use it my case?

Comment: `{'xxxx' : [112, 113, 114], 'yyyy' : [123, 124, 125]}`

Comment: Ahah..so searching can be done by iterating over the other list?

Comment: If you want to search, you can keep the IDs in a set (rather than a list) for constant lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary (which is similar to a hash table in `c`). Have in mind that dictionaries offer **O(1)** access to the value of a specified key. So since in your case the values (113,114 etc...) are all different between them, you could use them as keys and through them have **O(1)** access in the corresponding names (e.g. xxxx, yyyy, etc...)

```
>>> d = {
...     112 : 'xxxx',
...     113 : 'xxxx',
...     114 : 'xxxx',
...     123 : 'yyyy',
...     124 : 'yyyy',
...     125 : 'yyyy',
... }
>>> print d[114]
xxxx
```

**Update**

To store multiple values for one key you could use a `list`.

*1st way*

```
>>> d = {
...     112 : ['xxxx'],
...     113 : ['xxxx'],
...     114 : ['xxxx'],
...     123 : ['yyyy'],
...     124 : ['yyyy'],
...     125 : ['yyyy'],
...     }
>>>
>>> d[114].append('zzzz')
>>> d.items()
[(112, ['xxxx']), (113, ['xxxx']), (114, ['xxxx', 'zzzz']), (123, ['yyyy']), (124, ['yyyy']), (125, ['yyyy'])]
>>> d[114]
['xxxx', 'zzzz']
```

---

*2nd way* (using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict))

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> l = [(114, 'xxxx'), (113, 'yyyy'), (123, 'xxxx'), (114, 'yyyy'), (125, 'xxxx')]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in l: d[k].append(v)
...
>>> d.items()
[(113, ['yyyy']), (114, ['xxxx', 'yyyy']), (123, ['xxxx']), (125, ['xxxx'])]
>>> d[114]
['xxxx', 'yyyy']
```

Comment: The idea seems to be nice, but how to I append values to them?

Comment: @Jack Updated the answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
IP = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
data = (112, 113, 114, 115, 116)

mydict = {}
mydict[IP] = data

print mydict

hunt = 114

if hunt in mydict[IP]:
    print("{} is in {}".format(hunt, IP))
```

Here's the tutorial on dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: This is a great Idea too.